# How do I return an object of instancetype from a category method on a class cluster

Tags: objective-c

I would like to write a category on `NSString` that respects the subclass currently being used (so calling the function inside on `NSMutableString` should return an instance of `NSMutableString`, etc):

```
@interface NSString (HashTagUtilities)
- (instancetype *)stringWithHashTag;
@end
```

The implementation of this category is

```
- (instancetype)stringWithHashTag {
  return [self.class stringWithFormat:@"#%@", self];
}
```

However, because `NSString` is a class cluster, calling this method actually crashes:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
>   NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method
>   -initWithFormat:locale:arguments: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class __NSCFString: Create a concrete instance!'

My question is, is there any way to write a category like this -- one which has a method which returns an instance of the correct subclass for all current and future subclasses of the superclass being extended?

Comment: It is not typical that a `-stringWith...` method would return a mutable string when called on a mutable string. (Well, there aren't any `-stringWith...` methods, but similar methods don't do that.) Such methods are typed `NSString*`, not `instancetype`. Also, the private subclasses can have specific semantics, like a length limit or the value being from a small hard-coded list, that would not be appropriate for a different string, even if you're just prepending a `#`. So, you should let `NSString` pick the right one.

Answer (score 2):

While, as @Avi pointed out, the short answer *appears* to be no, Mike Ash did it here : https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html.

Here's an excerpt :

> The technique is to simply add a category to the cluster class instead of subclassing it. People often subclass simply to add new methods, and not to modify existing functionality. In Objective-C, you can add new methods in a category:

```
@interface NSArray (FirstObjectAdditions)
- (id)my_firstObject;
@end

@implementation NSArray (FirstObjectAdditions)
- (id)my_firstObject {
    return [self count] ? [self objectAtIndex: 0] : nil;
}
@end
```

So, according to Ash, it should work, and there's not problem in subclassing a class cluster. But it doesn't work !

Here's why :

As Apple's doc (here, on NSData, but it's true of any class cluster) notes,

> ...objects are not actual instances of the NSData or NSMutableData classes but instead **are instances of one of their private subclasses**.

The problem lies in the fact that you return an instancetype. `instancetype` is a hint to the compiler that the return type is the class in which the method is declared. The compiler is a bit silly, and just takes `NSString` as the receiver of the `stringWithFormat`. It doesn't know that, at runtime, the class won't be `NSString` but **one of its private subclasses**.

In your case, `__NSCFString` doesn't answer to the `initWithFormat` method (`stringWithFormat` seems to boil down to a `initWithFormat` call, as the error points out). For a more obvious case, take `__NSCFConstantString`, which is the type of any `@"string"` declaration. As it is instantiated by the ObjC runtime before you make any use of the string and perfectly immutable (you can't initialize, dealloc, or modify it), so it has no method of type `init`, so a call to `initWithFormat` fails, so a call to `stringWithFormat` fails, so you can't call `[@"hashtag" stringWithHashTag]`, so your code will fail in *at least* one case without any previous warnings, so it's doomed.

Thus, the core of the problem resides in `self.class` : you cannot be sure of the receiver type, or if it will answer your call. My suggestion is :

```
@interface NSString (HashTagUtilities)
- (instancetype)stringWithHashTag; //NOTE that there is no need for a * after instancetype - it's like id, it's already one
@end
@implementation NSString (HashTagUtilities)
- (instancetype)stringWithHashTag {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", self];
}
@end

@interface NSMutableString (HashTagUtilities)
- (instancetype)stringWithHashTag;
@end
@implementation NSMutableString (HashTagUtilities)
- (instancetype)stringWithHashTag {
    return [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", self];
}
@end
```

I have two categories : one for NSMutableString and one for NSString.
The NSString one *always* return a dynamically created `NSString`, whatever private subclass it may actually become, so I'm sure it won't fail.
<s>Finally, the NSMutableString one uses the mutable characteristic of its class, so I don't have to instantiate another string</s> This doesn't work, because *`__NSCFConstantString` is actually a subclass of `NSMutableString`*. How weird. So, I just instantiate a new string.

EDIT : As @RobNapier has very rightly pointed out

> We should really avoid any cleverness around them [the class clusters]. There's no way to know if you've tested all the corner cases. Are there other private string classes? Maybe. Will iOS 10 add more? Maybe. **Tread carefully**

Really. **Tread carefully** with these, they're not easy beasts, as we've all just seen.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question: my goal in writing this category was to return an object *of the same type as the receiver of the message*. Hence the use of `instancetype`, which, as you observe, has no meaning at runtime. Mike Ash's category simply reimplements `firstObject`, which returns some random object from the array.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer appears to be: no.

I would actually have expected your code to work, as `self.class` should return the concrete class type.  Your circumstantial evidence, however, points to `NSString` manipulating its internal classes to the point that they lie about what they are.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why exactly you believe self.class should return the concrete class type? Is there any documentation specifying this? How would it know the concrete class at runtime? It seems to me that manipulations of the classes in the cluster would be necessary so that they *did* return their concrete class type.

Comment: I don't "believe that it should"; I simply would have expected it.  After all, given the meaning of the `class` method, one would have to go out of ones way to lie about it.  All it is doing in the typical case is returning the `isa` pointer, which is a pointer to the instance's Class.  Apparently class clusters manipulate the `isa` pointer to lie about the class type.

Answer (score 1):

I think @PercevalFARAMAZ covers the main points, but I want to bring forward and expand on one of his notes.

The string `@"x"` is of class `__NSCFConstantString`. Your code would then be (if it worked the way you're asking it to work):

```
[__NSCFConstantString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", self];
```

That's nonsense, since constant strings are compiled into the binary. This string would have misbehaving memory management. Similarly, if your string is short (and you're on a 64-bit platform), it may be stored in a tagged pointer.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"short"] // NSTaggedPointerString
```

But this only works if the string is small enough to fit in a tagged pointer (something `NSString` determines at runtime when picking the correct subclass). If your hash were too long, then again, this would become impossible to fulfill and you'd crash. There is no promise that internal private types can be initialized using arbitrary strings, so your basic approach is going to be very fragile.

Because of Core Foundation bridging, it gets even weirder. The actual class may be a `CFStringRef` with a custom allocator. It may not even be *possible* to get that allocator (the destructor is stored in the struct, but not the allocator). So you'd be stuck again. There are just a huge number of corner cases when you get down inside of class clusters.

Comment: I hadn't considered the tagged pointer case, thanks for bringing it up. With that said, I would think that as part of fulfilling the contract of being a subclass of `NSString` (those classes do subclass `NSString`, right?) these classes should be able to, when confronted with a string that they cannot describe, return an instance of something that they are kindOfClass of, which fulfills the contract which the caller *expected*; that the returned object is of the "concrete" class (perhaps "public" would be the more appropriate term in this case).

Comment: "Subclass" gets very murky when you consider `CFStringRef`. It's actually bridged to look like a subclass, but the implementation is a bit different. I think your suggestion would lead to very unpredictable behavior. Clear "don't do that" rules are better than getting back somewhat random results. If you call `[NSNumber numberWithBool:4.0]`, do you want it to be a float (or maybe a double, or an NSDecimal, or what?) instead of a Bool? And that's a public interface; here you're asking a private one to "fix" incorrect calls.

Comment: All that said, class clusters have been long known in ObjC to be a mess. I can't think of any new ones that Apple has added, and Swift doesn't continue the tradition. The contract made by `NSString` has always been murky (is it immutable? No, it doesn't promise that.) Swift has tried another approach.

Comment: To go further on a class-cluster mess subject, the code I suggested didn't work because *__NSCFConstantString is actually a subclass of NSMutableString*. HOW WEIRD...

Comment: @PercevalFARAMAZ Yeah, I was just testing your code and ran into exactly that. Blew me away. Really drives home how tricky class clusters are and how we should be really avoid any cleverness around them. There's no way to know if you've tested all the corner cases. Are there other private string classes? Maybe. Will iOS 10 add more? Maybe. Tread carefully.

Comment: @RobNapier I copied a bit of your comment in my answer (with credits), is it OK ?